# Is there anything "lower" than Assembly, when it comes to talking to the processor?

Tags: assembly

I often hear people say you can "theoretically write direct-instructions to the CPU", but is there anything more "direct" than Assembly that's humanly possible to write, which can then be executed without any "Assembling" from semantics in to machine instructions?

I realize you can't write voltages, but bear with me here.... is there a such thing existing?

Comment: Real programmers use Butterflies. http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: @Zak That's not even valid! 01001100011010010110101101100101001000000111010001101000011010010111001100100001 :P

Comment: Early microcomputers (which is as far back as my experience extends) had a row of switches representing the address and memory bits.  You'd enter a program by flipping the switches.

Comment: I'm not 40+ years old to have had much experience in punch cards.  lol.

Comment: Actually punch cards predate microcomputer switches by quite a bit (I _am_ 40+ yo, and then some).

Comment: If you're talking about my comment, I was just stating that antler mentioned flipping switches, which goes back to the earliest days of the microcomputer revolution (Altair and so on). Punched cards, and computers of the non-micro variety, were in use well before then.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I am old enough to have done this.  The 'read first sector and jump to it' boot code had to be entered on every power up with 24 bit switches and load/store toggles :)

Comment: My Uncle was an EE for the Army Air Force and worked under the likes of Grace Hopper and John Von Nuemann.  When I tried to brag once about having booted a PDP-11 by manually entering the boot code using the console switches he just smiled and mentioned that he had to "load" those first OS's by hand-wiring them and then later "patching" them by using a soldering iron.(!)  From then on when my colleagues used to play "*Real Programmers ...*", I would always say "*Real Programmers debug with a soldering iron.*"  Nobody ever topped that one.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, Hollerith punch cards pre-date *computers* by quite a bit.  They were first invented in 1889, and used in the U.S. Census of 1890.

Answer (score 6):

Assembly is an abstraction on top of the op codes (operation codes) of the CPU.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode

List of x86 op codes:

http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

You can in fact program at the op code level (and I did that in college).  To do that on, say, DOS, you would use a hex editor and type into a file the header specified by the COM or EXE format and then start writing binary instructions that represent the op codes, and the binary representation of data that the op codes may act on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE_file

Comment: So how do I write opcodes that are independent of a specific executable format or OS(like just for a flat-binary file consisting of some MOVs, JMPs, CMPs, INT calls, etc.)?

Comment: @Pie_Rack_Girl opcodes are architecture dependent not necessarily OS dependent (except for system calls and such). And for system calls only the values in the opcodes are dependent on the OS (unless some weird OS implements Ring 1 and Ring 2 security, most just use Ring 0 and 3

Comment: For the record, the MS-DOS COM executable format *was* a flat binary. If you're targeting DOS, just compile your assembly source into a COM file. If not, compile into an object file, and use an appropriate tool to extract the code section.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: The OP is asking about directly entering op codes... not starting with assembly source.  To do that, one would have to open a new (binary) file, hand-enter the COM header (or EXE header) and then start entering op codes.

Comment: @Pie_Rack_Girl: You need *some* OS to load your file from disk, place it into memory, and set the instruction pointer to the first op code (although I did program an old Motorola processor in college that allowed entry of op codes into memory addresses using a hex key pad...).  Once the OS has loaded the file into memory and set the instruction pointer, the first byte encountered will be interpreted as an op code and the program will run from there.  Added a link to a list of x86 op codes.

Comment: I am writing my own OS, @EricJ.

Comment: The old DOS command line debugger allowed for assembling interactively straight into memory. Combined with the writeout command, you could create bona fide COM files with it. See if any modern debuggers allow the same.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Sure.  A hex editor with a list of op codes can accomplish the same :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's the machine code itself which you can insert into memory (depending on how well "protected" your environment is). There's little difference between compiling and assembling code other than the complexity of mapping source code to machine instructions.

And some processors actually have even lower levels such as microcode, but they're rarely accessible for general use.

Comment: @Pie_Rack_Girl, if by all you mean all modern ones, possibly. But if by all you mean all CPUs that have ever existed, I'd be more circumspect :-)

Comment: @Pie_Rack_Girl It's the differnce between CISC and RISC architecture.

Comment: no, most processors are not microcoded.  x86 happens to have a strong history of microcoding but it is not the norm.

Comment: There used to be some processor where you could fool with the microcode. Can't remember which one or how long ago that was.

Answer (score 0):

Machine language, as others have said. It's not unheard of that some CPU-level commands are not exposed in the assembly language - there's no mnemonics. Intel's infamous `LOADALL` comes to mind first - it was present in the CPU, but the assembler won't recognize it.

To use it, one would insert the relevant bytes directly into code by using the `db` assembly command.

If the question is - how can you write machine language without an assembler, the answer is - use a hex editor.

EDIT: sometimes, the assembly itself is more high level than one would like. The MIPS assembler is known for having built-in macros - mnemonics that expand to one or more commands, depending on the specifics of the operands and command line options. ARM in Thumb-2 mode does the same. This has to do with the underlying instruction set being deliberately stunted (RISC).

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, when I was bringing up a new circuit board with a CPU chip on it, I had to start by programming hex values into a ROM chip to get things started running.

Every CPU chip has some convention for what it does when the power is applied. Usually it loads something from a fixed location in memory and either uses it as a memory address from which the first instruction is loaded or uses it as the first instruction to execute.

Back to the new board. After programming the ROM chip, the chip was plugged into the board and power was applied. It was a pain to figure out if it was doing the right thing. Perhaps the new hardware was working. Perhaps it wasn't. I used an oscilloscope to watch the data and address lines on the CPU to see if it was a recognizable pattern. Since the processor was so simple in one case, that was enough.

Once you know it is actually coming up, you start using a cross assembler (or even a cross compiler) writing the low level code for the thing to run. It generates the hex bytes and those get burned into another ROM in the pattern the processor needs to execute. Pretty soon you have it working. (Or maybe not so soon.)

I only did this twice that I remember. In one case, the little board just had to listen for bytes coming in a hardware port and respond to them by sending other bytes out another port. That was the whole connection to the outside world. (It actually is similar to today's web services. Bytes come in and bytes go out.)

It is challenging and frustrating but very fulfilling. I'm glad I did it. I don't want to do it any more.